Is this EEPROM write procedure on STC microcontrollers correct? Any alternative?
I'm working on a STC15W204S microcontroller, a small, cheap and capable 8051 microcontroller. So far, with the flexibility of SDCC, using the provided STCAI-ISP software and the datasheet (which is full of examples), I've been able to figure out most of the things, thanks to previous experience on other microcontrollers. But something about the EEPROM seems off to me. The datasheet states (chapter 9):

The embedded EEPROM consists of several pages. Each page contains 512 bytes. Dealing with flash, the user must erase it in page unit before writing (programming) data into it. Erasing flash means setting the content of that flash as FFh.

Please, correct me if i'm wrong in something, but, isn't wiping an entire sector, each time I need to write a single byte, reduces drastically the lifespan of the EEPROM itself? Even if it doesn't, I think it's a big waste of time and resources having to first wipe a random sector for it to be writable, to then, copy the contents of the non-writable sector to the writable sector, to then, do the same procedure in order to return the data to the original place.
I googled a while, and I wasn't able to find any information about alternative paths or ways to store data on a non-volatile memory on STC microcontrollers

"Capable" compared to what? A potato? 8051 was infamous as the by far least code efficient MCU ever made, all categories. Even when compared to other horribly inefficient MCUs like PIC or HC05.

Mostly you are right, it depends on the details. And the data sheet has several minor flaws, from the few things I read (typos in the examples, strange wording, ...).
In principle all flash memory is a special kind of EEPROM, which is derived from EPROM technology. A common characteristic are the processes to change the bits. "Erasing" means to bring bits from 0 to 1, and "writing" means to bring bits from 1 to 0.
Some devices include the logic and state machines to erase single bytes before writing them. Others do not, and this is the case here. Actually the EEPROM of the STC15W204S is organized in pages of 512 bytes, which can only be erased as a whole.
If you want to rewrite a byte that will bring at least one bit from 0 to 1, you need to erase its page.
If you want to rewrite a byte that will bring only bits from 1 to 0, you don't need to erase its page.
The data sheet states:

On-chip EEPROM with large capacity can be repeatedly erased more than 100 thousand times.

If your application will not exceed this number, you can erase the page before you write new data. Yes, each erasure will stress the memory a bit, not to mention the additional time for this procedure.
If you store more than the byte to change in its page, you will need to copy the current content to RAM, modify the byte, erase the page, and write all bytes of the page back. Cross your fingers that there is no power outtake during this process, and take measures.
There is some work-around, if you need to update a value frequently:

Use a page exclusively for this value. This avoids the copying.
Use an array for the value. At each update, invalidate the former value by zeroing it, and write to the next cell. Do this only if the values actually changes.

The final line is that this EEPROM is apparently not meant for frequently changed data.

I should've explained for what I'm using this chip. Its used on a ultrasound cartridge, to keep track of how many uses are left. On my code there are only two bytes that are constantly being written. The machine that uses these cartridges subtracts "uses" sequentially, and given that these cartridges can be used around 60 to 80 thousand times, cell lifespan is something I have to take care on. I'll try to implement that "invalidation" way of writing data, so that the eeprom can last the entire lifespan of the cartridge itself. Thanks for the clarification!

@fpp You can count the uses with single bits, for example. Each use is a single bit changed from 1 to 0. This gives you 4096 uses per page before the necessity to erase it. Use another page to count the overflows. -- Prepaid cards for public phones used such a method, IIRC. Back in the time there were public phones. :-D

Its something I would've never thought of hahaha.
What I ended up doing was to write the two bytes, and when i needed to write again, the program moves by two the write address. So, I only need to wipe the sector after 256 "updates". This is backed with a function that searches the last written byte and the first writable byte when the uC is first powered up


Please, correct me if I'm wrong in something, but, isn't wiping an entire sector, each time I need to write a single byte, reduces drastically the lifespan of the EEPROM itself?

The datasheet you've linked states that on-chip EEPROM (and FLASH for that matter) "can be repeatedly erased more than 100 thousand times." A single program/erase cycle doesn't drastically reduce the lifespan of the EEPROM.
But you have to be mindful about the program/erase limitations. If you'd overwrite a specific cell once every second, you can expect it to fail after 28 hours.

I googled a while, and I wasn't able to find any information about alternative paths or ways to store data on a non-volatile memory on STC microcontrollers.

You can interface an FRAM chip to your controller. These chips have much better endurance (in the range 1013 .. 1015 program/erase cycles).

Thanks for the suggestion. Cell lifespan is something i have to keep in mind. the application doesn't allow me to add external components, so I'll have to find a way around. Thanks for the suggestion anyways!
